# Command for switching desktops in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, batch, autohotkey, multiple-desktop

Is there a command to switch to a specific desktop in Windows 10 (or alternatively open an application on a specific desktop which achieves kind of the same effect since windows will automatically switch to that desktop)

The idea is to write a batch or autohotkey script to switch to specific desktops with just one keyboard shortcut each, you know like is out-of-the-box functionality for every single desktop environment in Linux that supports multiple workspaces, and Windows 10 obviously lacks...

If there isn't, does anyone maybe have an idea how to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change shortcut key for switching between virtual desktops in windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/940342/how-to-change-shortcut-key-for-switching-between-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10), also see [Windows 10: Change shortcut keys to switch between desktops](http://superuser.com/questions/948616/windows-10-change-shortcut-keys-to-switch-between-desktops?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yeah, I guess since I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing it's a duplicate. There's no answer to it yet though, but I upvoted and favorited that other one, this one can be closed, I'll just add the command prompt thing as a suggestion in the comments for that question. I just marked it as an answer despite it not having one yet.