# Switch virtual desktops in Windows 10 like in Dexpot

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, virtual-desktop

In Dexpot (which is great software, but has issues on Windows 10) you can switch desktops by hovering cursor over taskbar and using back/forward buttons on mouse. That's really nice and fast way of switching between desktops with just one, swift mouse click.
Is it possible to add such usability to Windows 10 Virtual Desktops?

Comment: Not an identical duplicate but it should help you answer your questions: http://superuser.com/questions/940342/how-to-change-shortcut-key-for-switching-between-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10 I've looked into this before, natively this isn't supported

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/tree/master it can accomplish the features you just described. Dexpot certainly has even more features, but Autohotkey is lightweight and can enhance Windows 10 Virtual Desktop considerably.